# Dataproc: Spark driver and executor log locations and related configs

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I'd like to know which configs affect where Spark driver and executor logs are stored on Dataproc, and what's the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

See [Dataproc job output and logs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-job-output) for the configs. The following are the ways to get the logs.

### Commands and Queries

#### gcloud

Run the following command to get the driver logs when `spark:spark.submit.deployMode=client`. The output also includes the `driverOutputResourceUri` which is the log location in GCS.

```
gcloud dataproc jobs wait <job-id>
```

#### Cloud Logging

To query YARN container logs (which includes driver and executor logs when the related properties are set) for a cluster in Cloud Logging:

```
resource.type="cloud_dataproc_cluster"
resource.labels.cluster_name="..."
resource.labels.cluster_uuid="..."
log_name="projects/.../logs/yarn-userlogs"
```

To query driver and executor logs for a job in Cloud Logging:

```
resource.type="cloud_dataproc_job"
resource.labels.job_id="..."
resource.labels.job_uuid="..."
```

Alternatively, if you don't know the job ID/UUID, you can use cluster name/UUID to query job logs associated with the cluster:

```
resource.type="cloud_dataproc_job"
labels."dataproc.googleapis.com/cluster_name"="..."
labels."dataproc.googleapis.com/cluster_uuid"="..."
```